# XmlDocument doesn't work after OpenFileDialog

Tags: c#, xml, xmldocument, openfiledialog

This is a really weird one. I was writing an app that writes an XML file. On some occasions however the file would not be created/overwritten.

I managed to track down the specific events required to cause it to fail to write and I separated it out into a standalone program:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        bool doFileOpenFirst = false;

        if (doFileOpenFirst)
        {
            OpenFileDialog dialog = new OpenFileDialog();

            dialog.CheckFileExists = true;
            dialog.Filter = "Image files|*.bmp;*.jpg;*.png";

            dialog.ShowDialog();
        }

        // Just write a trivial XML file
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        XmlDeclaration dec = doc.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0", "UTF-8", null);
        doc.AppendChild(dec);// Create the root element

        XmlElement root = doc.CreateElement("Database");
        doc.AppendChild(root);

        doc.Save("Trivial.xml");
    }
}
```

Now if you run this, you will see it initially works. 
Now make doFileOpenFirst true. Before it writes the XML it will present you with a dialog for opening a file. 
If you use this dialog to select a file (any file; *not* "Trivial.xml"), the XML Save afterwards will fail. Silently.
If you hit cancel in the OpenFileDialog, the save will work fine.

So there's some issues with a file handle here perhaps, but what is the workaround? You will see that forcing a Dispose of OpenFileDialog doesn't help.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should place these code that open dialog and save xml in to Form's Load Event.

Comment: OK, but this example was just quickly done to show the problem. In the real code both the OpenFileDialog and XmlDocument.Save are manually triggered by the user and happen long after initialization or loading.

Answer (score 1):

Your dialog (OpenFileDialog) and your XML saving code are independent from each other. So showing dialog or not will not cause problems with XML saving especially when selecting some other file in dialog.

Also to help you I've checked your code and steps by me and XML is saving anyway, with or without OpenFileDialog. So suppose your problems depends not from open file dialog. In sample you provided there is no problem.

Comment: Same response as for cacoroto: the code consistently fails for me but I'm locked to an old framework (2.0) because I'm on a friend's laptop. If it worked for you then this must be the cause. Thanks for trying out the code for me.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to work fine! I tried and worked as supposed to.

No problems opening a random Image File:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Xml;

namespace StackOverflow
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        bool doFileOpenFirst = true;

        if (doFileOpenFirst)
        {
            OpenFileDialog dialog = new OpenFileDialog();

            dialog.CheckFileExists = true;
            dialog.Filter = "Image files|*.bmp;*.jpg;*.png";

            dialog.ShowDialog();
        }

        // Just write a trivial XML file
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        XmlDeclaration dec = doc.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0", "UTF-8", null);
        doc.AppendChild(dec);// Create the root element

        XmlElement root = doc.CreateElement("Database");
        doc.AppendChild(root);

        doc.Save("Trivial.xml");
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Just ran it again still doesn't work for me. But I'm writing this on a knackered old laptop and it's VS2005 (therefore .NET 2.0). Having it work on your machine cacoroto prob means this is something that has been fixed. Thanks (sorry if wasted anyone's time).